# DotNet Maui send a message from MainActivity.cs to MainPage.xaml.cs using the WeakReferenceMessenger

Tags: c#, android, maui

I'm using a barcode scanner from Newland and use "intents" to capture the barcode in MainActivity.

Once I have a barcode I use:

```cs
WeakReferenceMessenger.Default.Send(new MyMessage(msg));
```

to send the barcode, just a string of 12 characters or less.

In my MainPage.xaml.cs I have this:

```cs
WeakReferenceMessenger.Default.Register<MyMessage>(this, (r, m) =>
{
    MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
    {
        OnMessageReceived(r, m.Value);
    });    
});
```

It never gets called. I have tried it without the `MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>` but it makes no difference.

Before MessagingCentre was deprecated it worked fine.

Can anyone suggest a solution, please?

I'm only interested in Android as it's on a barcode scanner.

Thanks

Pete

I've tried all the permutations of the WeakReferenceMessenger and the debugger shows the message is being sent.

Comment: It's hard to tell what could be wrong with such little information and code. Please make sure to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). When and where do you call `WeakReferenceMessenger.Default.Send(new MyMessage(msg));` and `WeakReferenceMessenger.Default.Register<MyMessage>(...);`?

Comment: With breakpoints on those two lines (Send, Register), are both breakpoints reached? Is Register reached before Send? [Making sure the receiving code is ready.]

Comment: The breakpoint is reached on the send and it has the correct value from the barcode reader. Nothing happens on the mainpage.  This, of course, used to work perfectly with MessagingCentre.

Comment: Following on from Julians' comment  I thought I would create a copy to publish here. The same code works fine in the latest maui release, now I can move on. Thank you everyone.